# dnsmasq returns 127.0.0.1 for lookup itself

Tags: linux, networking, dns, dnsmasq

This is a follow up to the question, 
[Ping to dnsmasq's host resolvesto 127.0.0.1](https://superuser.com/questions/544873/ping-to-dnsmasqs-host-resolvesto-127-0-0-1), because that answer doesn't work for me. It should work -- I found another one having the same answer:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=470391

In both above cases, the cause was having dnsmasq's hostname listed as `127.0.0.1` in the `/etc/hosts` file. But mines doesn't:

```
$ head -2 /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain           localhost
192.168.2.100   jupiter.myhost.dyndns.org       jupiter
```

but dnsmasq's hostname is still resolved as `127.0.0.1`:

```
$ nslookup jupiter 
Server:         192.168.2.100
Address:        192.168.2.100#53

Name:   jupiter
Address: 127.0.0.1
```

What's wrong?

**Update:**

I'm using dnsmasq as my DNS server, and I didn't put any configuration regarding dnsmasq's hostname in dnsmasq's configuration. So, regarding the A record, this is all that I know:

```
$ dig jupiter 

; <<>> DiG 9.9.3-rpz2+rl.13214.22-P2-Ubuntu-1:9.9.3.dfsg.P2-4ubuntu1 <<>> jupiter
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 28464
;; flags: qr aa rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;jupiter.                         IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
jupiter.                  0       IN      A       127.0.0.1

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.2.100#53(192.168.2.100)
;; WHEN: Wed Jan 15 22:39:19 EST 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 39
```

Comment: What A record for `jupiter` set in the zone file of DNS server?

Comment: Thx. OP updated.

Comment: So, your DNS server is returning `127.0.0.1` on request to resolve `jupiter`. That is why `nslookup` shows `127.0.0.1`. Now we need to set correct A record for name `jupiter`.

Comment: and to do that with `dnsmasq`...?

Comment: Well I am not familiar with dnsmasq, but I looked at Wikipedia article about it. It looks like it just forwards data to/from real DNS server. How is your network setup? Do you have any DNS server? Or dnsmsq is only thing of this sort you have?